# Windows Remote Desktop - connect to a PC that has multiple monitors

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, remote-desktop

I encountered the following problem:
There is a windows 10 PC (enterprise) that has 3 monitors connected to it (extended desktop).
Is there any way that I can use Remote Desktop from my single monitor windows 10 PC (enterprise) to connect to the other PC and somehow run three apps each on a different monitor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when you RDP to a computer, the target computer sees your monitor(s).

Windows will not take into account the monitors physically connected on the remote computer because they are useless in this context.